# add key and value in array in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am trying to update an array in reducer

```
let initialState = {
count: 0,
todos: [],
id:0,
 }

const authReducer = (prevState = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_TO_DO:
        console.log(action.todo)
        
        return {
           ...prevState,
            todos: prevState.todos.concat(action.todo)
        }
    default:
        return prevState;
}
}
```

And I am getting array in the form

```
todos:['qwerty', 'abcdef']
```

But I want in the form of

```
todos:[{id:'1', todo:'qwerty'},{id:'2',todo:'abcdef'}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert `todos:['qwerty', 'abcdef']` to your expected format, you can map it:

```js
var todos=['qwerty', 'abcdef'];
var result = todos.map((todo, i)=>({id:i+1, todo}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce for this task

```js
const todos = ['qwerty', 'abcdef']

const data = todos.reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
  return [...acc, {
    id: index + 1,
    todo: rec
  }]
}, [])

console.log(data)
```